# Yii2 dynamically loading class from name

Tags: php, yii2

I struggle with this problem for a while - and the reason is probably trivial.

**Background**

I've created parser module for my Yii2 application so I can call it from other places (mobile app, etc.) to get data from various websites. There may be many parser classes, all implementing same interface.

**Project structure**

```
...
/modules
    \_ parser
        \_components
            \_parsers
                \_SampleParser.php
        \_controllers
            \_DefaultController.php
        \_Parser.php
...
```

I've removed some code for better readability.

DefaultController.php:

```
namespace app\modules\parser\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\modules\parser\components\parsers;
use app\modules\parser\components\parsers\SampleParser;

/**
 * Default controller for the `parser` module
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    
    private function loadParser($parserName){
        
        return new SampleParser();  // if I leave this here, everything works okay
        $className = $parserName.'Parser';
        $object = new $className();
        if ($object instanceof IParseProvider){
            return $object;
        }
    }
    
...
     public function actionIndex()
    {
        $url = "http://google.com";
        $parser = 'Sample';
        $loadedParser = $this->loadParser($parser);
        $response = $loadedParser->parse($url); 
                
            
        \Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return $response->toJson();
    }
...
```

SampleParser.php:

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\parser\components\parsers;

use app\modules\parser\models\IParseProvider;

class SampleParser implements IParseProvider {
    
    public function canParse($url){
        
    }
    
    public function parse($url){
        
    }
}
```

Right now everything works more or less ok, so I guess I'm importing correct namespaces. But when I remove `return new SampleParser();` and let the object to be created by string name, it fails with error:

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Class 'SampleParser' not found

with highlighted line:

> $object = new $className();

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try again with help of Yii:

```
private function loadParser($parserName)
{
    return \yii\di\Instance::ensure(
        'app\modules\parser\components\parsers\\' . $parserName . 'Parser',
        IParseProvider::class
    );
}
```

Remember that `ensure()` throws `\yii\base\InvalidConfigException` when passed reference is not of the type you expect so you need to catch it at some point.

If you are using PHP < 5.5 instead of `IParseProvider::class` you can use full class name with it's namespace.

P.S. remove `use app\modules\parser\components\parsers;` unless you have got class named `parsers` you want to use.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed unnecessary using. BTW your method raises `Call to undefined method app\modules\parser\models\IParseProvider::className()` - and thats correct, that's just pure interface. When I include static `className()` method in both interface and `SampleParser`, I get `Cannot call abstract method app\modules\parser\models\IParseProvider::className()`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot your class does not extend `yii\base\Object` - you can use `IParseProvider::class` if you are using PHP >=5.5

Comment: It works! `IParseProvider::class` instead of `IParseProvider::className()` did the job. Thank you very much :) Please add this information to your answer so I can accept it.